# SQL How to display data before a certain date

Tags: sql, date

I have a couple of tables. One is a **worker table** which displays worker code, firstname and lastname. 
**Job dates** which shows worker code, date of job start, end and job area code.
**Supervisor** has worker number, firstname, surname and job area code.
**Job area** has job area code name and supervisor.

What I'm trying to do is display the worker code before date 10/09/10
Since I am new to this, I'm trying to do it all written and theory first before making the database.

Does this sound right? I'm not too sure about the date thing.

```
select worker
From Job Dates
where job start < '10/09/10'
```

In theory this sounds right to me, but does it somehow need to tell the query it is a date stamp?

I then want to find the surname of workers and the surnames of their supervisor if the workers started the job before the 10/09/10? I'm guessing this will be with a JOIN?

Thanks

Comment: you'll need to cleanup your sql, but what you have will work if job_start is a datetime column. Cannot really help much without your table structure. Good Luck.

Comment: The job_start column will read as: 10/09/10 same as the job_end. Thanks

Comment: You need to show the key parts of the schema of your table.  Column names don't usually contain spaces; when they do, they must be enclosed in delimiters.  The format for a DATE literal is formally `DATE '2010-09-10'`, but different DBMS have other notations that also work.  You should specify which DBMS you're using, too.

Answer (score 12):

You're on the right track. Not knowing the schema of your database, your ultimate query will look something like this:

```
select w.surname, s.surname
From worker w INNER JOIN JobDatesTable jdt on w.id = jdt.id
              INNER JOIN SuperVisor s on w.id = s.id
where jdt.jobstart < '20101009'
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Just wondering whether there is any reason worker does not have a w behind it in the way that JobsDate does? My last line should read according to my schema?

    where jdt.jobstart < '10/09/10'