# Find all tables with a specific column name + where value is lower than X

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help in searching our database. So we have this problem that we need to know all tables, with the column_name "sysmodified" and see if there are any entries before a specific date (25-sep-2019).

I tried to find the answer on google and stackoverflow, but I either get an answer how to get the results before 25-sep within 1 table [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456676/sql-how-to-display-data-before-a-certain-date), or results how to get all tables, which has this column_name [Example2](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-find-tables-that-contain-a-specific-column-in-sql-server/).

Using the code I have so far (see below), we know that there are 325 tables, which contain the column_name "sysmodified". I could manually use example 1 to get my information, but I was hoping for a way to get the results that I need with just one query.

This is what I have so far:

```
USE [database2]
GO
SELECT t.name AS table_name, 
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%sysmodified%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

However if I try to enter anything like sysmodified < '20190925'. I get errors

```
WHERE c.name LIKE '%sysmodified%'
AND t.sysmodified < '20190925'
```

or this approach, which also results in errors

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name, sysmodified,
```

based on (but I cannot add 325 columnnames in FROM?)

```
SELECT
  title,
  primary_author,
  published_date
FROM
  books
WHERE
  title LIKE 'The%'
```

Hopefully someone could help me with an approach how to tackle this problem. We use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 (if that might be relevant).

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple dynamic sql to put together. This should produce the results you are looking for as I understand your requirements.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select distinct TableName = ''' + object_name(object_ID) + ''' from ' + quotename(object_name(object_ID)) + ' where ' + quotename(c.name) + ' < ''20190925'' UNION ALL '
from sys.columns c
where name like '%sysmodified%'

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10) --removes the final UNION ALL

select @SQL
--once you are comfortable that the dynamic sql is correct just uncomment the next line
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I do get results now, but I do not see any [database2] in there. How do I know it takes the right database? I also only get the results if I uncomment the last line, otherwise it will just show "No column name"

Comment: Because when you select the dynamic sql if there are no rows in sys.columns it will not populate the variable with anything. Remember that sys.columns is only for the database you are running the query in. If you want multiple databases you can run this on each database. Or you can extend this to include multiple databases.

Comment: I have put `USE [database2] GO` before your query now. I guess this fixes my issue, because the query seems to run fine? I needed to do this for 1 database anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from GMB is right.  Fastest way I can think of an answer is using Dynamic SQL.

I would build a query to loop through or create a union select statement across all tables that have that column.  Something like:

(skeleton)

```
DECLARE @N_SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
Find all tables that have a column with '%sysmodified%'
Build a dynamic query of (union style) from above like:
SET @N_SQL = ''
SELECT @N_SQL = @NSQL + 'UNION SELECT ' [SCHEMA] + '.' + [TABLENAME] + ' AS TABLENAME FROM ' + [SCHEMA] + '.' + [TABLENAME] + ' WHERE ' + [COLUMN] + ' >= '''<DATE>'''

SELECT @N_SQL --just to see what that string looks like
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL RIGHT(@N_SQL, LEN(@N_SQL) - 5)  --Trimming out the first word "UNION"
```

So, the above might work.  Might need a bit of clean up, but its a skeleton idea.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My knowlegde of SQL if fairly basic. If I use your code I get all kinds of errors. 
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Find'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@N_SQL".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@NSQL".
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' >= '''`

Comment: This is full of syntax and logical errors. You have a select statement that pulls SCHEMA, TABLENAME and COLUMN but you have no FROM. This is barely a rough sketch. It simply doesn't work in its current form.